# Class constructor NgbDatepickerI18n cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, datepicker, ecmascript-5, ng-bootstrap

After updating from Angular 5 to Angular 8, I am getting this error while opening a modal window with a DatePicker from the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap package. The error is thrown at an attempt to create one of both provider objects (NgbDatepickerI18n and NgbDateParserFormatter). Whole application builds and runs fine except for this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-datepicker-termin',
    templateUrl: './datepicker-termin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./../datepicker.style.scss', './datepicker-termin.style.scss'],
    providers: [NgbDatepickerConfig,
        {provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: DatepickerI18n},
        {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDatepickerParserFormatter}
        ],
})
export class DatepickerTerminComponent {
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.1.5",
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.3.21",
...
"engines": {
    "node": "12.14.0"
...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "target/www/app",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@angular/*": [
                "../node_modules/@angular/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/main/webapp/app",
        "src/test/javascript/"
    ]
}
```

Switching the target/lib to es6/es2015 doesn't help. 
Using core.js at latest version as recommended by jhipster for browser compat. Babel is not in use.
Few "unrelated" packages are outdated. Could this cause the problem? Many thx for help or any hints.

Comment: any luck? I'm facing the same issue at the moment.